# Want to move window off top of desktop

Tags: windows-7, desktop-management

I am on Windows 7 Pro. I want to move my browser window upwards so that it is partly off my desktop. The recommended way to do this is to activate the 'move' command with alt+space, then move the window up with the arrow key. It does move - but it immediately snaps back down again, so that it's fully on the desktop. Is there any way to get it to stay up there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not sure what else I can add. What do you feel is missing; what is confusing?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is the Aero Snap feature.

To disable the Aero Snap feature, begin by clicking on Start and then entering Ease of Access Center into the Search Programs and Files search box. Press Enter.

At the bottom of the list is an option titled Make it Easier to Focus on Tasks. Click on this option.

Near the bottom of the window, you will see an option titled Make it Easier to Manage Windows. Under this option, check the box titled Prevent Windows from Being Automatically Arranged When Moved to the Edge of the Screen.

Comment: Good thought Gantendo, thank you.  But that box is already checked.  (I found AeroSnap mega-irritating on moving to W7!)

Comment: Still unsolved, folks!